# Update style on scroll event in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am attempting to change the color style of my header when a user scrolls the page, however, my `onScroll` method doesn't even seem to be firing. Can someone please tell me why and how I can fix this? The `onScroll` method is being called on the bottom `TemplateWrapper` component. Also, if you have any other suggestions on how to do it differently, I'm all ears! Thanks!

```
const headerStyle = {
      background: 'grey',
      marginBottom: '1.45rem',
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      zIndex: '99'
}

const modHeader = () => {
  headerStyle.background = 'white'
  console.log('scroll')
}

const Header = () => (

  <div className='header'
    style={headerStyle}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        margin: '0 auto',
        maxWidth: 1160,
        padding: '1.45rem 1.0875rem',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      }}
    >
      <h1 style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        <Link
            to="/"
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            Gatsby
        </Link>
      </h1>
      <h2 style={{ margin: 0 }}>  
        <Link
          to="/about"
          style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecoration: 'none',
          }}
        >
          About
        </Link>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
)

const TemplateWrapper = ({
  children
}) => (
    <div onScroll={modHeader}>
      <Helmet
        title="Gatsby Default Starter"
        meta={[
          { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
          { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
        ]}
      />
      <Header />
      <div 
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 960,
          padding: '0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem',
          paddingTop: 0,
        }}
      >
        {children()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

export default TemplateWrapper
```

Comment: Directly modifying the values of your `headerStyle` object will not trigger a rerender as the code seems to expect, you will need to call `this.setState` to accomplish that

Comment: @RobM. OK that makes sense, but shouldn't it at least by console.log?

Comment: Assuming your div is large enough to be scrollable, yes

Comment: OK, that's the strange thing to me, is that nothing is showing up in console.log - I now understand why the style can't change, but the function isn't even being called.

Comment: Try setting the `height` of the `div` with the `onScroll` event to something very large like `2000px`

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add an eventlistener in 
componentDidMount and store your value in state, you need to rerender your component onScroll,

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
     this.setState({
       // your flags
      });
    });
   };
```

**Note:** if you want to add event listener to your div, you can access to it by ref in react like this,

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   this.listener.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
     this.setState({
       // your flags
      });
    });
   };
render(){
   return( 
       <div ref={(listener) => { this.listener = listener }}></div>
    )
 }
```